# tensorflow.contrib.memory_stats.BytesInUse - where to put in the graph?

Tags: tensorflow

In the module `tensorflow.contrib.memory_stats`:

As I understand `MaxBytesInUse`, it will give me the maximum memory usage so far since the lifetime of the session, right?

I was wondering about `BytesInUse`. I thought it would give me the maximum memory usage from a single session run but that doesn't seem to be the case because it returns a quite low number but I know that I'm quite close to the limit of my memory. So I guess it returns the current memory usage when that operation kernel is executed? But that is then very much non-deterministic. If it starts right at the beginning, it will be low (only the variables). Via `tf.control_dependencies`, I could make it such that it executes at the very end, but there TF likely will have released any used memory already, so it will also be low (again only the variables), right? So, where does it make sense to put it in the graph? But probably this never will give me what I want, i.e. the maximum memory usage during a single session run, right?

So, is there any way to get what I want, i.e. the maximum memory usage of a single session run?